# Turn input text to a button

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I've been trying to replicate this feature:

[image: stackoverflow example]

and:

[image: Gmail example]

I'm using JS and Vue to build my web application. I would really appreciate any tips on how to continue in this mess I have created. So far I have managed to add a button element to the end of my editable `div`, but this is not the solution I am looking for, and neither can I come up with a better one to replicate my previous examples.

Idea is to have the same kind of bubble button added not by typing, but pressing another button. The bubble button position is important, as it would reference an already existing array of names, which will be sent out by `nodemailer` inside email text body.

```js
insertCandidate(areaId) {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
  var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
  var caretPos = txtarea.selectionStart;
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerText = 'candidate name';
  btn.className= 'candBtn';
  btn.id="candBtn"
  btn.setAttribute("v-on:click", "alert('tere')");
  txtarea.appendChild(btn);
  console.log(txtarea.innerHTML)
  this.btnHidden = true
  var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, caretPos);
  var back = (txtarea.value).substring(txtarea.selectionEnd, txtarea.value.length);
  txtarea.value = front + btn + back;
  caretPos = caretPos + btn.length;
  txtarea.selectionStart = caretPos;
  txtarea.selectionEnd = caretPos;
  txtarea.focus();
  txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
},
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"
     id="rejectArea">
  {{rejectText}}
</div>
<v-card-actions>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <button v-if="!btnHidden"
          v-on:click="insertCandidate('rejectArea');">candidate name</button>
```

Comment: you should try this http://www.vue-tags-input.com/#/

Comment: I checked it out, still kind of not the full feature im looking for, or I am just not able to use it in my situation. The vue tags input module creates a different input field, where only tags can be used, however, i need to use the tags on a regular input field

Comment: why don't you want to use this: https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/chips ??

Comment: So, you want to insert a new button on the click of a button (or another item)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but I give it a shot:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    isLoading: false,
    items: [],
    model: null,
    search: null,
  },
  methods: {
    closeChip(item) {
      this.model = this.model.filter(e => e !== item.symbol)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    model(val) {
      if (val != null) this.tab = 0
      else this.tab = null
    },
    search(val) {
      // Items have already been loaded
      if (this.items.length > 0) return

      this.isLoading = true

      // Lazily load input items
      fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          this.items = res.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-autocomplete v-model="model" :items="items" :loading="isLoading" :search-input.sync="search" chips clearable hide-details hide-selected item-text="name" item-value="symbol" label="Search for a coin..." solo multiple>
              <template v-slot:no-data>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-title>
                    Search for your favorite
                    <strong>Cryptocurrency</strong>
                  </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:selection="{ attr, on, item, selected }">
                <v-chip
                  v-bind="attr"
                  :input-value="selected"
                  close
                  color="blue-grey"
                  class="white--text"
                  v-on="on"
                  @click:close="closeChip(item)"
                >
                  <v-icon left>mdi-coin</v-icon>
                  <span v-text="item.name"></span>
                </v-chip>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
                <v-list-item-avatar
                  color="indigo"
                  class="headline font-weight-light white--text"
                >
                  {{ item.name.charAt(0) }}
                </v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
                  <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.symbol"></v-list-item-subtitle>
                </v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-action>
                  <v-icon>mdi-coin</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-action>
              </template>
            </v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

In this snippet data is loaded async, then you can choose which data element to add to the input field as a chip. The chips then can be removed, etc.